# How to persist entities inside for loop JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, for-loop, jpa

I am trying to save entities inside a for loop. But it only save the last entity in the database. my entity looks like following.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_departments")
public class Users_Departments extends AbstractBaseEntity {
......
}
```

I have written a common crud method to save the entity in the database as following.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public T create(T entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.refresh(entity);
    return entity;
}
```

In the service method, I am saving list of users with department and other details in the database as following.

```
 @Transactional
    public List<Users_Departments> addUserstoDepartments(Long deptId,List<Long> useridList){
       Users_Departments object = new Users_Departments() ;
       List <Users_Departments> userDeptList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int a=0 ; a < useridList.size();a++){                   
            object.setDepartment(departmentDao.find(deptId));
            object.setStation(userDao.find(useridList.get(a)));
            object.setCreatedDate(new Date());
            object.setUpdatedDate(new Date());

            Users_Departments newlyCreated = users_departmentsDao.create(object);
            userDeptList.add(newlyCreated);
        }
        return  userDeptList;
    }
```

When debugging this method returns the list with updated values, but each and every item has the same value as the "id" . Therefore only the last record is available in the database. I think all other records have been replaced. Is there any reason for that?
Can't I create entities inside the for loop? How is it possible?

Comment: its still the same object. move `Users_Departments object = new Users_Departments() ;` inside the loop

Comment: @XtremeBaumer thank you soo much :)

Comment: As a side note, there's no need to call `refresh` inside `create` (and `flush`ing the changes manually is probably redundant as well, unless you need the autogenerated id)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should instantiate the `Users_Departments object` each time inside the loop, like this:

```
List <Users_Departments> userDeptList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int a=0 ; a < useridList.size();a++){   
    Users_Departments object = new Users_Departments();             
    object.setDepartment(departmentDao.find(deptId));
    object.setStation(userDao.find(useridList.get(a)));
    object.setCreatedDate(new Date());
    object.setUpdatedDate(new Date());

    Users_Departments newlyCreated = users_departmentsDao.create(object);
    userDeptList.add(newlyCreated);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are saving always the same object (hence updating it) move the

```
Users_Departments object = new Users_Departments() ;
```

inside the loop to create a new one everytime